# JavaScript application for showing the weekend dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, weekend

I thought a lot - I tried but I could not solve it. I need a JavaScript application that shows the nearest weekend dates in the current date.

If it's a weekend now, give it the dates of this weekend, if not, then next weekend's dates.

I'm waiting for your help.
Respects.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far? Maybe it just needs a tweak.

Comment: What is the nearest weekend to Wednesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `Date` constructor.

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var saturday;
var sunday;
if(day === 0 || day === 6){ //0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday
    saturday = date;
    sunday = new Date(saturday.getTime());
    sunday.setDate(saturday.getDate() + (day === 0 ? -1 : 1));
    if(day === 0){
        var temp = saturday;
        saturday = sunday; //Confusing, but they are actually the wrong dates, so we are switching the dates
        sunday = temp;
        temp = null; //Free up some memory!
    }
        
}
else{
    //This is the complicated part, we need to find when is the next Saturday
    saturday = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), (date.getDate() + 6) - day);
    sunday = new Date(saturday.getTime());
    sunday.setDate(saturday.getDate() + (saturday.getDay() === 0 ? -1 : 1));
}
date = day = null; //Free up some memory!
document.body.innerText = [saturday, sunday];
```

To get the date, use `saturday.getDate()` or `sunday.getDate()`.Remember that `Date` months are 0-based. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but this code is only showing Saturday. I need Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: I'll update that. But do you want it on both cases or only one case?

Comment: Actually, the only thing I need is Saturday and Sunday dates.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's OK. Respects.

Comment: This doesn't get the "nearest" weekend, it gets the current or next weekend. I.e. given a date for Monday, it returns the next Saturday and Sunday, not the one just past (which would be the one closest to Monday).

Comment: @RobG "If it's a weekend now, give it the dates of this weekend, if not, then next weekend's dates." I think the OP meant differently.

Comment: The OP is ambiguous, there is also "*…shows the nearest weekend dates*", but I guess your interpretation is correct. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var chosenDay = new Date();
    var box = [];
    var counting = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      chosenDay.setDate(chosenDay.getDate() + counting);
      var day = chosenDay.getDate();
      var dayy = chosenDay.getDay();
      var month = chosenDay.getMonth()+1;
      var year = chosenDay.getFullYear();
      box.push({day: day, dayy: dayy});
      counting = 1;
    };
```

Now to find Saturday and Sunday

```
box.map(function(obj) {
 if (obj.dayy === 6) {
  console.log('Saturday found');
  alert(obj.day);
}; 
 if (obj.dayy === 0) {
  console.log('Sunday found');
  alert(obj.day);
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the "nearest" weekend as being the previous weekend for Monday and Tuesday, and the next weekend for Thursday and Friday. You didn't provide any information on what to do with Wednesday.

However, from other answers it seems you want either the current weekend for Saturday and Sunday and or the next weekend for weekdays.

The following is a little more concise than other answers:

```js
/* Get nearest weekend to the provided date
** @param {Date} date - date to get weekends nearst to
** @returns {Array} array of Dates [Saturday, Sunday]
*/
function getNearestWeekend(date) {
  // Copy date so don't mess with provided date
  var d = new Date(+date);
  // If weekday, move d to next Saturday else to current weekend Saturday
  if (d.getDay() % 6) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6 - d.getDay());
  } else {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay()? 0 : 1));
  }
  // Return array with Dates for Saturday, Sunday
  return [new Date(d), new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1))]
}

// Some tests
[new Date(2017,0,7),  // Sat 7 Jan
 new Date(2017,0,8),  // Sun 8 Jan
 new Date(2017,0,9),  // Mon 9 Jan
 new Date(2017,0,12)  // Thu 12 Jan
].forEach(function(d) {
  var opts = {weekday:'short', day:'numeric', month:'short'};
  console.log('Date: ' + d.toLocaleString('en-GB',opts) + ' | Next weekend: ' +
              getNearestWeekend(d).map(d =>d.toLocaleString('en-GB',opts)).join(' and ')
  );
});
```